# Multi-language store- Changing custom menu's language dynamically

Tags: magento, menu, header

I am doing Multi-language store in magento. i have some custom menu in header section like how to order, Help etc. .
now currently these menu i have given direct link like

```
<li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>help">Help</a></li>

<li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>howtoorder">how to order</a></li>
```

i am not sure how multi-language feature will work with this menu.. How can i write these top menu as if It will change with language change.
any suggestions will be helpful for me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Any text** that is hard-coded into your template needs to be wrapped in the translation helper.

```
echo $this->__('Help');
```

But make sure the block it applies to has a helper declared, otherwise you'll need to load the generic helper.

```
Mage::helper('core')->__('Help')
```

Then, you can edit the relevant translation CSV file. By putting "Help" in the first column, and the translation in the second column.

Although, you'll be able to use translate in-line once you are using the above PHP.